# Flip Maybe and List

Tags: haskell

I want a function that takes in a list of `Maybe a`, and returns `Just [a]` if all contents are `Just a`, otherwise returns `Nothing`.

```
f :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
-- f [Just x, Just y ] = Just [x, y]
-- f [Just x, Nothing] = Nothing
```

I think it doesn't have to be `Maybe` and `List` but any `Functor` `Applicative` or `Monad`, but I can't think up the way.

Comment: You want `sequence`or `sequenceA`. `sequenceA` works for any `Applicative ` (`Just` in your example) in any Traversable (`[]` in your example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great example of where [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle) comes in handy. It's a search engine where you can enter a type signature and get the functions that match—even if they are more polymorphic.

Entering `[Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]` we get [a bunch of results](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BMaybe+a%5D+-%3E+Maybe+%5Ba%5D).

[image: The top few Hoogle results.]

The first one is:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

We can try this out in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let xs = [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]
Prelude> sequence xs
Just [1,2,3]
Prelude> let xs = [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
Prelude> sequence xs
Nothing
```

Hey, look at that: exactly what we were looking for! So the function you want is `sequence` which also happens to work for types other than `Maybe`.

Comment: I did use Hoogle but I was assuming both had to be the same class's instance for some reason and missed it. Thank you!